# Networks of three actors data set

Tags: data-request, network-structure

A network of one actor is a network where all nodes are of the same type, like the Facebook network where all nodes are humans. Two actor networks (Bipartite) are networks where there are two kinds of actors, like book and writer, where there are links between two different actors and not between the same actor. Similarly, the three actor networks is composed of three different disjoint sets and links can happen to be between any two nodes from any two different sets. I am looking for data sets for the 3 actors networks. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Search for "tripartite network" and you'll find a lot of scholarly articles which might contain datasets.

Enzyme-catalysed metabolic pathways can be modeled as tripartite networks. Educts + Enzymes -> Product.

But I think this can be reduced to bipartite networks, as far as I remember from reading the [book 'Networks', by Mark Newman](https://books.google.de/books?id=LrFaU4XCsUoC&pg=PP107&lpg=PP107&dq=%22tripartite+network%22+metabolism&source=bl&ots=86LyYGjj3n&sig=AXfXSb2-BmO3H0MiC1ROJXpHL2Y&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tripartite%20network%22%20metabolism&f=false). (See Fig. 5.1)